# Excel: how to remove leading characters of a string with a function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, hexadecimal

I have a text column in Excel full of hexademical values like this:

```
0000000000000c10
00000000000036f0
00000000000274da
00000000000379e0
```

Which function can help me strip the leading 0's up until the first non-0 character?
Desired output:

```
c10
36f0
274da
379e0
```

This would help me feed the HEX2DEC function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to convert to decimal then back again. The `HEX2DEC` worksheet function will only accept 10 digits/characters as input but `RIGHT` will take care of that. Instantly converting back with `DEC2HEX` (while leaving the optional *[places]* parameter out of the equation) should result in a trimmed HEX value.

[image: HEX to DEC to HEX]

The formula in B1 is,

`=DEC2HEX(HEX2DEC(RIGHT(A1,10)))`

Fill down as necessary. The `DEC2HEX` function could pad leading zeroes up to 10 places but if you need your leading zeroes back for a maximum of 16 digit placeholders then,

`=RIGHT(REPT(0, 16)&B1, 16)`

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found it.

Assuming the values are in a table, and its column is named "Column1":

```
=REPLACE([@Column1],1,FIND(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE([@Column1],"0","")),[@Column1])-1,"")
```

This will produce the desired output as shown in the question.

The core of the solution is handled by this formula, which counts the 0's before the text value we're looking for.

```
=FIND(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE([@Column1],"0","")),[@Column1])-1
```